Want to add tag at the top left of a product card
I want to make a tag for a card on my website for a new product. My idea is to have something like this

in the top left corner of the card.
I am writing about this, because I need help making the css for it.
I tried making it just a square with rounded corners, but I didn’t like the look. Here is the example of the layout.

Here is the html and css for the card:


#games div {
  background-color: #3A7BCD;
  border-radius: 7px;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: clip;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#games div *:not(img) {
  margin: 10px;
}

#games div img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
<div>
  <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/9FJYqQKg/Screen-Shot-2024-05-08-at-4-22-24-PM.png" alt="Banner image">
  <h2>
    Title
  </h2>
  <p>
    Description
  </p>
</div>




What help do you need, exactly? Your question title suggests you're struggling to position the "tag," but in the question it seems that you need help creating the tag (the shape) itself. Which is it? Please bear in mind that [SO] questions should have one question only, rather than multiple largely independent questions (even if the questions all relate to the same project).

@DavidThomas Sorry you didn’t understand. I wanted a way to make the circle shape with the spikes in CSS. I ended up going with an image

Have a look at this example, where I used a simple div instead of an image: It has position: absolute, the parent has position: relative to act as the position root. The left and top parameters can be adjusted as needed, as well as the transform: rotate(...) angle. But the principle should be clear:


#parent {
  background-color: #3A7BCD;
  border-radius: 7px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  width: calc(100% - 60px);
}

#parent *:not(img) {
  margin: 10px;
}

#parent img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
#new {
 width: 100px;
 height: 60px;
 background: green;
 position: absolute;
 transform: rotate(-25deg);
 top: -25px;
 left: -30px;
 border-radius: 8px;
 color: white;
 font-size: 30px;
 line-height: 60px;
 text-align: center;
}
<div id="parent">
<div id="new">NEW</div>
  <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/9FJYqQKg/Screen-Shot-2024-05-08-at-4-22-24-PM.png" alt="Banner image">
  <h2>
    Title
  </h2>
  <p>
    Description
  </p>
</div>




Hmm… not what I really wanted. I was looking for a shape with the ripples around the edges. Thank you, tho

Maybe I do something like that, but the image inside of the color

the ripples thing should be an image in png or gif format (in order to allow transparent areas) - you won't be able to create something like that with CSS

as I wrote: Adjust the position as needed with the top and left parameters

Thanks for the help! Stack Overflow needs more kind people like you.

Your problem is in the overflow property defined as clip, in this case in practice you are hiding all the content that overflows your element. A possible solution (although it may not be ideal) would be to wrap your element in a div with the same dimensions and then add the tag you want.

I don’t think you understood my question.
